# Can some one explain how the last output resulted for the below javascript code?

Tags: javascript

This is a javascript JSON parser [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_JSON.parse()) from mozilla website

```js
JSON.parse('{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": {"4": 4, "5": {"6": 6}}}', function(k, v) {
  console.log(k);
  return v;
});
```

Comment: We (maybe) try help fix broken code. We're not here to teach you what code does, or how it works.

Comment: I'm inclined to put the same level of effort answering this as you did in formatting it.  Next time you ask a question on SO, edit and format it properly.  This is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, Quentin was faster ;-)

to make things clearer I post it anyway:
the output is somthing like

```
k = "1", v = 1
k = "2", v = 2
k = "4", v = 4
k = "6", v = 6
k = "5", v = Object {6: 6}
k = "3", v = Object {4: 4, 5: Object {6: 6}}
k = "", v = Object {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: Object {4: 4, 5: Object {6: 6}}}
```

so the last key is the key of the whole = root object node and has no key

Comment: Thank you very much Wolfgang. This is really helpful, cleared (may be basic) ambiguity. So is this a general property for all JSON. Or a property more of javascript?

Comment: properties k and v are the properties in you pase function. As you can see the parse steps throw the json object recursively- so the last node handled is the root node ob the json tree and this name has no property name. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The outer-most object isn't a property of another object, so it doesn't have a property name associated with it.